# Anime about a group of ragtag characters adventuring in space

Tags: story-identification, anime, space

I am looking for an anime show I saw when I was young. The details I remember are not very clear since I saw it around 1994 to 1998.

The series had a space theme.

I remember the main character's friends, and possibly parents, turning to stone or into a statue because of some poison (in one of the episodes). The main character was looking for the cure. I think the parents were killed for good.

I somehow remember a character being called tetsuro or something similar.

I think the main character was young in it or it had some flashbacks of the character's childhood.

They had a group of ragtag main characters travelling through space themed adventures.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to take the [tour], to best understand how our site works. You've listed a fair amount of information on the anime you're looking for, but you still may want to look at [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/), to see if it helps you think of more information you can edit into your question. Some examples include: What country/channel did you see this on? How did the characters travel? if by spaceship, can you describe it at all?

Comment: There is a [TV Tropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TakenForGranite) on being turned to stone.  You might look at the anime & manga there to see if anything seems familiar.  Nothing jumped out at me reading through, but I don't know much about any of it.

Comment: Sounds like it could be Galaxy Express 999. The main character is a boy named Tetsuro and the show follows his adventures in space on a ship that looks like a train. I believe it's from the late 70's so the timeframe works, and I vaguely recall characters being turned to stone or glass or something in the original manga.

Comment: @Torisuda That sounds close enough that it's worth putting together as an actual answer.

Comment: @ConMan Yeah, but I'm lazy, so I'll leave it to someone else to find the pictures and quotes and whatnot to compile a real answer.

Answer (score 3):

Searching anime-planet for a series with a [main character named Tetsuro](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/all?name=tetsuro), I found *[Galaxy Express 999](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/galaxy-express-999)* (1978-1981).

> Ever heard of a flying train? Tetsuro, living on a dismal earth, wants to ride it to Andromeda so he can get a mechanical body that will enable him to live forever. With the help of the mysterious woman, Maetel, Tetsuro braves many adventures on his way to Andromeda, heading towards a showdown with Count Mecha, an evil tyrant that brutally murdered his mother for sport. Will Tetsuro have the inner strength to face this monster on his own turf?

There are also a number of sequel projects, including [Adieu Galaxy Express 999](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/adieu-galaxy-express-999), which is described as involving Tetsuro's attempt to get revenge for his mother's murder.

> Tetsuro Hoshino was once a boy willing to give anything to board the Three-Nine, including a promise to accompany a mysterious woman named Maetel to the other side of the Galaxy, if only to fulfill a vow to avenge the cruel death of his mother at the hands of the villainess Count Mecha. Now, two years after the events of Galaxy Express 999, Earth has become a battlefield, and Tetsuro is summoned to board the Three-Nine once more. All questions will be answered and all mysteries revealed as Tetsuro embarks on a journey the destination of which is unknown even to the Galaxy Express Railways locomotive C6248 itself... a journey which will reveal a secret so awful, even Maetel herself can hardly bear speak of it.